# Best Buy IdeaX using Rack on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, rack

I am attempting to create a fresh build of the [Best Buy IdeaX](https://github.com/BBYOpen/BBYIDX/) platform on Heroku.
I have followed all the instructions according to the git readme, but I am running into an issue.  Whenever I attempt to actually view the site, I get an "app crashed" error, and when I get the logs I see:

```
$ heroku logs
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:50: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/config/environment.rb:11
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2617d4c7-5a17-40a5-baa7-1bf450b1799b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-03-02T21:02:06-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-03-02T21:02:07-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET cold-light-156.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-03-02T21:02:07-08:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 76.169.212.8 | 796 | http | 503
2011-03-02T21:02:12-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET cold-light-156.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-03-02T21:02:12-08:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 76.169.212.8 | 796 | http | 503
2011-03-02T21:10:24-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-03-02T21:10:24-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `setup': You have already activated rack 1.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.1.0. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:16
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/config/boot.rb:114
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/config/environment.rb:11
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/42faa6dc-66fd-40ec-b13f-81025071634b/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-03-02T21:10:31-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-03-02T21:13:16-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET cold-light-156.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-03-02T21:13:16-08:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 76.169.212.8 | 796 | http | 503
2011-03-02T21:13:17-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET cold-light-156.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-03-02T21:13:17-08:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 76.169.212.8 | 796 | http | 503
2011-03-02T21:21:22-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-03-02T21:21:22-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `setup': You have already activated rack 1.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.1.0. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:16
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/config/boot.rb:114
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/config/environment.rb:11
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/2d1f21a3-b9b4-4419-825b-9051c5e453d0/home/.gems/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-03-02T21:21:30-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-03-02T21:21:31-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am new to using Rack on Heroku, but it seems like I need to use Rack 1.1.0 and Heroku has Rack 1.1.1...can I either change the Rack version on Heroku, or change the version required in the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We pushed an update for this yesterday. If you pull the latest code from https://github.com/BBYOpen/BBYIDX this issue is fixed and you should be able to follow the instructions in the README to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: cool, thanks guys! I had to remove the .gems file from the git repo with git rm .gems